# Duplicated records with UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Recently in production database I've noticed, that some indexes was corrupted.
While discovering this problem, I've found, that some tables with `UNIQUE` constraints has duplicated records.

For example, `session` table, that was created, when using `express-session` package with `connect-pg-simple` storage adapter:

```sql
with session_groups as (
  select sid, count(sid) "sid_count"
  from session
  group by sid
)
select *
from session_groups
where sid_count > 1
order by sid_count desc;
```

```
               sid                | sid_count 
----------------------------------+-----------
 dKaklpKjAqm48ZYG**************** |         5
 xonQ9KfXLOwopBtG**************** |         4
 2V9Lt7QuU1pUs0io**************** |         4
 yqNLs9uRDgzHmFsr**************** |         4
 wvLkoAJELXTUqTyF**************** |         4
 0IbKIAuKivD_BYRt**************** |         4
 wpBq0DkUmHzkA9eV**************** |         4
 vEuFfYbBBy_QVWpV**************** |         4
 GfFcYOybuaLIeKSv**************** |         3
 fSPqX8EVDIDklRT-**************** |         3
 WXmMi-3J2zQyJTij**************** |         3
 ipPZe9s3Wj_GBbtl**************** |         3
 7es96UX5MDQBsVP1**************** |         3
 3CqZRsIhYnG-vGyO**************** |         3
 wosZYDYWmzo6xvrr**************** |         3
```

NOTE: sid's are obscured with `***` for security.

How it was happen?
What to do with this problem?

Comment: Any operating system updates recently? https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/08/27/glibc-upgrade.html and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes

Comment: Does PostgreSQL agree there is a unique constraint, or does only `express-session` think so?

Comment: What is the table schema and the constraints? Did you `REINDEX`?